# Rubber with etex package

Tags: pdftex, e-tex, rubber

I am using `rubber` to compile my documents. In some of them (usually Beamer presentations), I use the `etex` package. In such a case, `rubber` aims to use as the command `elatex` to invoke the `e-TeX` engine for the compilation. But there is no such `elatex` command, so it does not work!

As mentioned in a [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/rubber/+bug/856449), a solution is to invoke `rubber` with the options `-d` (for PDF) and `-e 'set program pdflatex'` to force using the command `pdflatex` instead of `elatex`.¹ What is the problem then? Well, I'd like to invoke `rubber` simply with `rubber -d foo.tex` for instance.

A solution for avoiding command-line options is the use of *directives*, adding lines in the source such as:

```
% rubber: set program pdftex
```

But these directives seem to correspond to the `-c` option, that is they are given to `rubber` before it analyzes the sources. Therefore, it does not work in my case since after I tell it to use `pdftex`, it will read the line

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

and switch to `e-TeX`. (At least, it is how I interpret the behavior — I may well be wrong!)

**My question:** Is it possible to *really* force `rubber` to use some specific engine, with some directive in the source? Or (more or less equivalently) is it possible to give a directive in the source corresponding to a `-e` option instead of a `-c` option?

**A comment:** I am aware that the *right* solution would be to remove the bug in `rubber`, but since it does not seem to be maintained anymore, I am interested in a *pure `rubber` solution* if it exists!

¹ The `-e` option allows to set so-called *variables* after analysis of the sources, so that even though `rubber` has noticed the `etex` package, we can force it to use `pdftex`.

Comment: which tex distribution do you have? It is very rare not to have etex, and if you have pdftex without etex it must be _very_ old as etex and pdftex have been the same executable since some time last century in particular `latex` and `pdflatex` should both be built with etex extensions.

Comment: Hmmm, since I have TL2013 it does not qualify as *old*... Actually, what `rubber` does not find is the `elatex` command, and I have the `etex` command which simply calls `pdftex` (I just checked that following your comment). I thought `elatex` is to the `e-TeX` engine as `pdflatex` is to the `pdfTeX` engine... Now I'm a bit at a loss: Does someone has an idea where does the problem lies, and how to solve it?

Comment: there is no elatex as latex (and pdflatex) have been built on etex rather than classic tex for years. I don't know rubber but it is mis-configured: it should just be using latex

Comment: Thank you David, I'll update my question in consequence.

Comment: If `rubber` wants to call `elatex` or `pdfelatex` just define a couple of aliases: `elatex` should point to `latex` and `pdfelatex` to `pdflatex`. That's all.

Comment: Right... I'll do that. I let my question since maybe some `rubber` expert could give an answer to the question of a directive corresponding to the `-e` option, which I find interesting for its own sake.

Comment: @Bruno I'd recommend switching to arara.

Comment: @egreg: I'm afraid I don't see the point of `arara`. My use of `rubber` is to be able to compile my documents without thinking on the sequence of compilation. I feel like `arara` is just a specialized `make` program, and I don't see the difference with having a `Makefile`. Of course, I am aware no tool can be perfect for the compilation (some weird situations are not properly treated), but my goal is to have something which works *almost each time*.

Comment: @Bruno Sorry, but I don't see your point. With arara you exactly specify what you want to do, which is the same as with `rubber`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11413/discussion-between-bruno-and-egreg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent (later than 2007, I'd say) TeX distributions, there's no more a separate `pdfelatex` program, because `pdflatex` uses e-TeX extensions by default.

Older versions of `rubber` might have a different compiler modules for `pdfelatex`, but the most recent version (1.2) hasn't.

If your `rubber` insists in calling `pdfelatex` or `elatex`, just make  shell aliases for them, pointing to `pdflatex` and `latex` respectively.

Upgrade your `rubber` and this will be solved. Note also that with a LaTeX kernel from 2015/01/01, calling the `etex` package is not required any more.